# Error message for lmer table output with sjt.lmer

Tags: r

I need help creating a table for my linear mixed effects model. My code for the model works fine:

```
fit1 <- lmer(Temp~Dist+(1|Week)+(1|Pair), data=MinWinterTemps)
summary(fit1)
anova(fit1)
rand(fit1)
```

But when I try to create a table for the output:

```
sjt.lmer(fit1)
```

I get the error message:

```
Computing p-values via Kenward-Roger approximation. Use `p.kr = FALSE` if computation takes too long.
```

And when I try to make a table using `Broom` (tidy package) I don't get the output variables that I need. Please, can someone help me figure out how to create a nice looking table from the data I have for my lmer model?

Comment: Could you provide a subset of your data (e.g. using `dput`)? I have a suggestion to make but want to create an example using your data.

Comment: What you listed is not an error, it's just a message telling you that the analysis started. What happens next? Does it freeze or complete without returning anything? If it takes too long, have you tried using the argument `p.kr = FALSE` to see it it speeds it up?

Comment: what is missing from the `broom::tidy()` table? p-values?

Comment: Would still love to see a subset of the data for this problem :)